# How to post data to an external URL from a masterpage containing asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, post

I have to post five field values to an external url to process payment from an asp.net application. The external company gave me sample code in html. The problem is that I can't use html as I have to populate some of these values in the codebehind and use aspx pages. Since my website has a master page I can't use the line

```
 <FORM name=thisForm action="https://abc.com/xyz/default.asp" method=post>
```

Please let me know how to post these values using asp.net from code behind.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Since my website has a master page I can't use the line` This isn't true. You can set these properties in code-behind of any of your aspx pages, like this for instance:

```
Form.Action = "https://abc.com/xyz/default.asp";
Form.Method = "post";
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But still I have to send it from the code behind since I have to manipulate and populate some field values in the code behind.

Comment: @user466663, how exactly you need to manipulate these values? Can't you use javascript/jquery to do that, so you could avoid a complete postback to your server? You can always create a webservice/page method and call it using an ajax call if you need to do some processing on the server-side. Seems an easier solution to me than trying to create dynamically a new page and post it to another server afterwards. Here's an example of doing what you've just described - http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/546370-POST-through-code-behind-in-aspnet